# How to load values into JComboBox,depending on selection from another JComboBox?

Tags: java, ms-access, dependencies, jcombobox

Here is my code:

```
JComboBox unity=new JComboBox();
unity.setBounds(430,280,140,25);
unity.addItem("Pakistan");
unity.addItem("China");
unity.addItem("America");
unity.addItem("Japan");
unity.addItem("Bangladesh");
unity.addItem("Srilanka");
unity.addItem("India");
unity.addItem("Turkey");
unity.addItem("UK");
unity.addItem("Afghanistan");
unity.addItem("Iran");
unity.addItem("Iraq");
unity.setEditable(true);
uy.add(unity);

JLabel city=new JLabel("City:");
city.setBounds(350,320,100,25);
city.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
uy.add(city);
JComboBox cety=new JComboBox();
cety.setBounds(430,320,140,25);

cety.addItem("");
uy.add(cety);
unity.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent olala){
    if(unity.getSelectedItem().equals("Pakistan")){
        cety.addItem("Lahore");
        cety.addItem("Islamabad");
        cety.addItem("Karachi");
        cety.addItem("Rawalpindi");
        cety.addItem("Faisalabad");
        cety.addItem("Gujjranwala");
    }
}
});
```

But when i run the program,the block of if statement did not do anything.
What should I do,if I want to Load Values into `JComboBox`, depending on selection from another `JComboBox`?

Comment: Remove the semi colon `if (unity.getSelectedItem().equals("Pakistan"));`.  Your if statement is executing an empty body.

Comment: @Arjan I have removed that ; But still,it's not doing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you choose "China" first, then "Pakistan" again, and click on the down arrow of the `cety` combobox, you'll see the items.

You can easily debug and see when the method is called by adding a `println` like so,

```
        ...
        unity.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent olala) {
// DEBUG
System.out.println("itemStateChanged(): item = " + olala.getItem());
            ...
```

You'll notice that `itemStateChanged` *is* called when you select a different item.  If you start the program and see the comboboxes for the first time, they haven't changed state yet, the method hasn't been called, and `cety` is empty. You could make `unity` change state, by adding

```
        unity.setSelectedIndex(1);
        unity.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

at the end of your code.  Alternatively, you could just move all the `unity.addItem` lines to after the `addItemListener` so adding the first item to the list will trigger the event.

You'll need to clear the items before adding new ones, or selecting a couple of items in `unity` will result in a long list in `cety`. If you need an empty string in the list, you need to move that statement here as well,

```
            ...
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent olala){
            cety.removeAllItems();
            cety.addItem("");
            if (unity.getSelectedItem().equals("Pakistan")) {
                cety.addItem("Lahore");
                ...
```

You could then use a `switch` instead of a ton of `if` statements,  get the item from the event instead of `unity`, and get rid of the raw types:

```
    JComboBox<String> unity = new JComboBox<>();
    unity.setBounds(430, 280, 140, 25);
    unity.setEditable(true);
    uy.add(unity);

    JLabel city = new JLabel("City:");
    city.setBounds(350, 320, 100, 25);
    city.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    uy.add(city);

    JComboBox<String> cety = new JComboBox<>();
    cety.setBounds(430, 320, 140, 25);
    uy.add(cety);

    unity.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            cety.removeAllItems();
            cety.addItem("");
            switch (event.getItem().toString()) {
                case "Pakistan":
                    cety.addItem("Lahore");
                    cety.addItem("Islamabad");
                    cety.addItem("Karachi");
                    cety.addItem("Rawalpindi");
                    cety.addItem("Faisalabad");
                    cety.addItem("Gujjranwala");
                    break;
                case "China":
                    cety.addItem("Beijing");
                    break;
            //  ...
            }
        }
    });
    unity.addItem("Pakistan");
    unity.addItem("China");
    unity.addItem("America");
    unity.addItem("Japan");
    unity.addItem("Bangladesh");
    unity.addItem("Srilanka");
    unity.addItem("India");
    unity.addItem("Turkey");
    unity.addItem("UK");
    unity.addItem("Afghanistan");
    unity.addItem("Iran");
    unity.addItem("Iraq");

// This would be a workaround if you don't want to move the addItems:
//  unity.setSelectedIndex(1);
//  unity.setSelectedIndex(0);
```